# How to render 200+ view without performance issue in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am trying to make a game in react-native. I want to render 200+ views on the Game screen. Each View has a pressable functionality. Whenever I press the View I need to run a function that will change the View background color and update score on the game context. But Whenever I try to press any View it took some time to change the background and update the context.

**Note**

I am using the expo as a development environment and I am using a real device too.

**My View Component**

```
import { useEffect, useState, memo } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { gameContext } from "./gameContext";
import { Pressable, View } from "react-native";
function CheckBoxCom() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const { score, setScore } = useContext(gameContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    let time = setTimeout(() => {
      setActive(false);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 35000));

    return () => clearTimeout(time);
  }, [active]);
  const handlePress = () => {
    if (active) return;
    setActive(true);
    setScore(score + 1);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable onPress={handlePress}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: active ? "green" : "gray",
            margin: 3,
            borderRadius: 3,
            backgroundColor: active ? "green" : null,
          }}
        ></View>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}

export default memo(CheckBoxCom);
```

**Game Screen Component**

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import CheckBox from "./CheckBox";
import { gameContext } from "./gameContext";

export default function Game({ navigation }) {
  const { score, time, setTime, boxList } = useContext(gameContext);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const int = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prvTime) => prvTime - 1);
    }, 1000);
    setIntervalId(int);
    return () => clearInterval(int);
  }, []);

  if (time === 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    navigation.navigate("Score", { score });
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.textHeader}>
        <Text>Score : {score}</Text>
        <Text>Time Left: {time}s</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
          data={boxList}
          initialNumToRender={50}
          numColumns={12}
          renderItem={(i) => <CheckBox />}
          keyExtractor={(i) => i.toString()}
          scrollEnabled={false}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 40,
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
  },
  checkBoxContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    height: "80%",
    overflow: "hidden",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});
```

How can I run view function immediately whenever I press it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is slow is that when you press on a view, all 200+ `CheckBoxCom` components rerender. If they don't need to, we can improve performance by trying to prevent those unnecessary rerenders.

I believe the major bottleneck here is the `gameContext`. It groups together a lot of states and if any of these were to change, all components will rerender. It provides `score` state that you are reading within each `CheckBoxCom`. Whenever the score changes all `CheckBoxCom` components will re-render. If you change `handlePress()` to:

```js
const handlePress = () => {
  if (active) return;
  setActive(true);
  setScore(score => score + 1);
};
```

Please note the use of callback to update the score in the above handler. In this case, we don't need to read `score` from context, so we can remove it from the game context provider, only pass `setScore`. Removing `score` from the context provider is important because not doing so will rerender all components using the context even if you don't specifically destructure `score`.

Also, make sure you don't have a lot of state variables within a single context. Split it into multiple contexts if you have different states in there. In this way, you will be able to reduce unnecessary rerenders of the `CheckBoxCom` components.

Since your `CheckBoxCom` components have an internal state, using `React.memo()` will not help to prevent rerenders because it only works for rerenders resulting from changed props.

But if you are able to refactor them to lift the `active` state up to the parent i.e. something like `activeViews` or something (which could be a map of indexes which are `true` i.e. active), then you can pass the `active` state as a boolean prop to each `CheckBoxCom` component. And if we also pass `setScore` via a prop instead of via context, we can benefit from `React.memo()`. BTW it is not necessary to wrap `setState` methods with `useCallback()`.

The end result will be: `CheckBoxCom` components with zero internal states and no reliance on context, in other words, pure components i.e. components which work nicely with `React.memo()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use pagination in flatlist**

for ref: [Pagination in flatlist](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Platform,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      //Loading state used while loading the data for the first time
      serverData: [],
      //Data Source for the FlatList
      fetching_from_server: false,
      //Loading state used while loading more data
    };
    this.offset = 0;
    //Index of the offset to load from web API
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    //fetch('http://aboutreact.com/demo/getpost.php?offset=' + this.offset)
    fetch('https://www.doviz.com/api/v1/currencies/all/latest')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
       responseJson = responseJson.slice((this.offset*12),((this.offset+1)*12)-1)
                 console.log("offset : "+this.offset);

         console.log(responseJson.slice((this.offset*12),((this.offset+1)*12)-1));
      //Successful response from the API Call 
        this.offset = this.offset + 1;
        //After the response increasing the offset for the next API call.
        this.setState({
         // serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson.results],
         serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson],
          //adding the new data with old one available in Data Source of the List
          loading: false,
          //updating the loading state to false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
 
  loadMoreData = () => {
  //On click of Load More button We will call the web API again
    this.setState({ fetching_from_server: true }, () => { 
      //fetch('http://aboutreact.com/demo/getpost.php?offset=' + this.offset)
      fetch('https://www.doviz.com/api/v1/currencies/all/latest')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
           responseJson = responseJson.slice((this.offset*12),((this.offset+1)*12)-1)
            console.log("offset Load : "+this.offset);
          console.log(responseJson);
          //Successful response from the API Call 
            this.offset = this.offset + 1;
            
            //After the response increasing the offset for the next API call.
            this.setState({
              //serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson.results],
              serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson],
              fetching_from_server: false,
              //updating the loading state to false
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
    });
  };

  renderFooter() {
    return (
    //Footer View with Load More button
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.9}
          onPress={this.loadMoreData}
          //On Click of button calling loadMoreData function to load more data
          style={styles.loadMoreBtn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Loading</Text>
          {this.state.fetching_from_server ? (
            <ActivityIndicator color="white" style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} />
          ) : null}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            data={this.state.serverData}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                  {item.currency}
                  {'.'} 
                  {item.code}
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
            onEndReached={this.loadMoreData}
            onEndReachedThreshold ={0.1}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
            //Adding Load More button as footer component
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,height:80
  },
  separator: {
    height: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: 'black',
  },
  footer: {
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  loadMoreBtn: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#800000',
    borderRadius: 4,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btnText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```